# How can I add data by data class which is in list which is in another list? Or is there a better way?

Tags: kotlin

This is my declaration: `val areas = mutableListOf<MutableList<Point>>()`

My data class:

```
data class Point(
    val accuracy: Double,
    val latitude: Double,
    val longitude: Double
)
```

My attempt:

```
areas.add(mutableListOf(mutableListOf(Point[0].copy(accuracy = 0.0, latitude = 0.0, longitude = 0.0)))
```

This maybe can help to understand what I need: https://releases-f89f5.firebaseio.com/.json?fbclid=IwAR3Zso66lLJLQDX17K5LFuqByaJFLmKahg-TYrJF3BAZqhd3CbtFgqo9tug

I want to be able to change data of "Point" and also to add that mutable list of mutable list of "Point".

Answer (score 2):

`areas` is already the outer list. You have one too many nested `mutableListOf()`. Do this:

```
areas.add(mutableListOf(Point[0].copy(accuracy = 0.0, latitude = 0.0, longitude = 0.0)))
```

Or you can use `+=` in place of `add` to avoid having to keep track of that extra trailing parenthesis.

```
areas += mutableListOf(
    Point[0].copy(accuracy = 0.0, latitude = 0.0, longitude = 0.0)
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it tells me: `Classifier 'Point' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here` when I try to use your first example.

Comment: What is `Point[0]`? I was assuming you have some list named `Point` that you were pulling a value from. Seems like you don't have a list named `Point`. If you simply want to create a new Point from scratch instead of from copying another one, call the Point constructor.

Comment: It's a data class. You can see it in my question.

Comment: Point is a class. I don't know what `Point[0]` is. `[0]` would only make sense if you have a List or Array that is confusingly also named `Point`.

Comment: Your question code is taking the first element of some collection called ``Point`` (``Point[0]``). Then it makes a copy of that element with some of the values changed (all of them in this case, if you're always doing that you might just want to construct a new ``Point``). And then it's creating a new list containing that copy, which is being added to the ``areas`` list (assuming Tenfour04 is right and you didn't want that other list thrown in there too). If that's not what you want, you'll need to give a more detailed explanation of what you're doing, and maybe show more of the code